# Hola , buenos días , ¿alguien me resuelve esta duda con el problema de los caracteres especiales en Java NetBeans 13?

Tags: netbeans, java-8

Tengo problemas al tratar de correr un programa creado en java , programo en el NetBeans versión 13 , trato de ejecutar el programa con un buscador pero me sale algunos caracteres especiales , como por ejemplo si me apellido "Puicón" , me sale "PuicÃ³n" , o otro ejemplo con el apellido "Peréz" , y sale "PÃ©rez"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La código que utilize para solucionar el problema de la "ñ" por ejemplo , hice esto:

```
        String str5 = TNombres.getText();
        String str6 = str5.replaceAll("Ã±", "ñ");
        TNombres.setText(str6);
```

de ahí todo funciono correctamente , pero eso soluciono solamente el problema de la "ñ" , ahora lo demás caracteres siguen dando ese problema

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Click derecho en el proyecto->propiedades->Sources->Seleccionar Encoding cambia  el utf-8 por defecto por iso-8859-1

Comment: @Dramaturgo , buenas tardes , si el problema persiste , cual crees que pueda ser el problema? porque el registro lo guarda en un block de notas , pero en el block de notas lo guarda sin esos caracteres , por ejemplo , lo guarda "Pérez" pero cuando lo llamo al jtextfield , lo pone como "Ã©" , ya le cambie como menciono pero persiste , esta con el  --- Encoding : ISO-8859-1 , también limpie el código y lo volví a construir , cerré el NetBeans y lo volví a abrir pero persiste